# Informix Error to insert –32,768

Tags: java, informix

i have issue  while converting  large  value into short int in java using  .shortValue() and  inserting  into informix  column which is  of  type  smallint . The small int  ranges  from -32767 to 32767. but  short int  conversion returns  -32768 which is  not able to  insert into informix.suggest a solution with out change the  informix  column data type;

Comment: How small/large can your values get?  Are there more than 65534 values?

Comment: The documented range for Informix SMALLINT is -32767..+32767.  Clearly, -32768 is outside that range and therefore not valid for a SMALLINT.

Comment: @JacobG. The  values are coming  from external system .like  127752 .after  short  conversion it  returns  -32768